# Why can't a program be multiplatform when it only needs to be compiled on each platform it is to run on?

Tags: compilation, cross-platform

You may find the answer a bit obvious, and part of it is to me too.

But I'm wondering what parts of the code of a project usually need to be specifically designed for a specific platform, whether it was written in a high or a low level programming language?

If the question sounds a bit vague, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: multiplatform or crossplatform - what is the subtle difference? i think if you just need to recompile a code, the program then is encountered as crossplatform one, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between the two (correct me if i'm wrong). Though they are not to be confused with "platform independent" .

Answer (score 0):

Example could be the OS kernel methods, such as reading from files/network/memory. For example Windows provides different functionality/privileges than Linux when it comes to I/O and memory access.

Also, the machine/assembly code to which the code translates to depends on the underlying processor. So a C code must be recompiled sometimes to run on a newer version on Intel processor such as MEC.

Another reason could be a commercial version. Windows could make a C# code run on a MAC, by creating a .NET framework and a visual studio for MAC, but they chose not to do so, so that you are forced to write C# on Windows.

Comment: This is an open source implementation of the .NET framework. I was talking about the commercial aspect meant by Microsoft not the feasibility of doing it. Of course, you can take any programming language and wrap your own code generator over it

Comment: @mutafabar, quoting from you, ... "from Windosw [sic Microsoft] could make a [sic] C# code run on a Mac ...". They didn't chose to. You are right there, and that is their commercial right. But Microsoft isn't the only game in town is my point. So if Microsoft doesn't give us what we want, we can do it ourselves (open source). Let's agree not to nitpick though, OK?

Answer (score 0):

The question is general, so I will answer rather generally.

1) Like the previous post mentioned, anything that hooks into the essence of the OS needs to be code that works for that OS.

2) The lowest level code would be machine language / or assembly. This kind of code is not very crossplatform as it is code which will only run correctly on the machine that it was written for. That is an advantage of C, which is considered a low level language. Of course if you write C code for specific hardware, such as for instance a seven segment LED panel, that code will only work on another system if there is a corresponding seven segment LED panel in the target system.

One of the beauties of higher level programming languages is that you can generally write cross platform code which really only needs to be recompiled for the target system to run.

Then we could talk about interpreted languages such as Python, Ruby, or virtual machines like Java, Smalltalk, etc. If the target platform has an interpreter, such as "Python", as long as the source code is valide, it should run unaltered on a similar Python interpreter (I mean similar because you may have  version issue, or you may have graphical addon libraries, or other libraries).

As I type away, I realize that to do this question justice, one could write and write. Hmmm, maybe this question is TOO GENERAL???

CHEERS (of course I've left a lot of the story out)